# One-to-Many: How to get the same blog posts to show up for every user?

Tags: xcode, parse-platform

I was about to get One-to-Many up an running in no time. I signed into my app as a dummy user named "diva" and made posts that were successfully added to parse.com with no hassle. However, when I log out from the user account "diva,"  none of the posts show up anymore. I figured it was because of this code:

```
PFQuery *postQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Post"];
[postQuery orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];



[postQuery whereKey:@"author" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
```

Which makes sense because "currentUser" is no longer "diva." My question is how do I get the same blog posts to show up for every user as opposed to just the currentUser? How do I call the object ID for just one user?

I have tried:

```
[postQuery whereKey:@"author" equalTo:@"diva"];
```

but that didn't work. I have also tried:

```
[postQuery whereKey:@"author" equalTo:@"fu8CDOLeKu"];
```

"fu8CDOLeKu" being the object ID for the user "diva," that still doesn't work. What now?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSString *userId ="fu8CDOLeKu";
[postQuery whereKey:@"author" equalTo:[PFObject objectWithoutDataWithClassName:@"_User" objectId:userId]
```